# How to publish Multi-bitrate Stream from flash as3 application

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I need to publish Multi-bitrate Stream from flash as3 application. Is it possible?

The documentation is available only to publish it through "flash live media encoder".

Please share a link if there is any link/tutorial available for this.

Comment: could you clarify your question? Are you trying to encode video files from a swf or the IDE?

Comment: We are publishing via FMS(Adobe media server) and broadcasting our o/p stream via flash live media encoder (by Adobe).But we want to publish 3 bitrate streams from our own Action Script(Swf file).

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flashmediaserver/